# Kohana 3: has_many and order_by

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

How can i order a query that uses the has_many association in Kohana 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like `$model->items->order_by('fieldname')->find_all()`? `__get()` method returns Query_Builder object, not a Database_Result, so you can add QBuilder's conditions (where/order_by/etc) for your needs.

Comment: What do you mean? In my example model has_many items, so $model->items is a has_many-related object.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Kohana_ORM::__get()` implementation - you cannot.

All it does is just composing `where` condition without any possibility of adding a sort:

```
    elseif (isset($this->_has_many[$column]))
    {
        $model = ORM::factory($this->_has_many[$column]['model']);

        if (isset($this->_has_many[$column]['through']))
        {
            // Grab has_many "through" relationship table
            $through = $this->_has_many[$column]['through'];

            // Join on through model's target foreign key (far_key) and target model's primary key
            $join_col1 = $through.'.'.$this->_has_many[$column]['far_key'];
            $join_col2 = $model->_table_name.'.'.$model->_primary_key;

            $model->join($through)->on($join_col1, '=', $join_col2);

            // Through table's source foreign key (foreign_key) should be this model's primary key
            $col = $through.'.'.$this->_has_many[$column]['foreign_key'];
            $val = $this->pk();
        }
        else
        {
            // Simple has_many relationship, search where target model's foreign key is this model's primary key
            $col = $model->_table_name.'.'.$this->_has_many[$column]['foreign_key'];
            $val = $this->pk();
        }

        return $model->where($col, '=', $val);
    }
```

But you can write your own class `ORM` and reimplement `__get` there. You need to rewrite a little the part I've given above (if `isset($this->_has_many[$column])`) or pass the control to the `parent::__get($column)` otherwise. In this case you're free to add one more parameter to `_has_many` setup array like `order_by` and use it to order by the related models.

In pseudocode:

```
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM
{
    public function __get($column)
    {
        $result = parent::__get($column);

        if (isset($this->_has_many[$column]) && !empty($this->_has_many[$column]['order_by'])) {
            $result->order_by($this->_has_many[$column]['order_by']);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sheeks06: not a builtin one, but you can easily extend with your own.